# How to move thumbnail panel in gwenview to right edge?

Tags: kde, kde-4

In the KDE application `gwenview`, how do I move the thumbnail panel to the right edge? I've tried everything obvious, including dragging everywhere, looking through the documentation, searching the web and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select "Configure Gwenview..." from the "Settings" menu
2. Select the "Image View" tab
3. Set Thumbnail Bar orientation to vertical

Comment: thanks, i just did not see it - it has rather countraintuitive name.